# Php - using include/require_once inside function

Tags: php

I am creating a class "*DBQuery*" that contains all the database query functions such as **insert, select, delete, ...**

Everything is working fine when I create database connection inside the **INSERT** function. But i want separate the configuration so that i can include it in any other files and pages.

**configuration.php**

```
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("DATABASE", "edubits");

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOSTNAME . ";dbname=" . DATABASE . ";", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

**class.php**

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Sunusi Mohd Inuwa
 * Date: 11/18/2018
 * Time: 11:02 AM
 */
class QUERY
{
    function INSERT($table, $data, $conn)
    {
        include_once('../configuration.php');

        // variable declaration
        $columns = "";
        $valueset = "";
        $values = "";

        //loop
        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns = $columns . ', ' . $column;
            $valueset = $valueset . ', ?';
            $values = $values . ', ' . $value;
        }

        //trimming the first comma from the result above
        $columns = ltrim($columns, ',');
        $valueset = ltrim($valueset, ',');
        $values = ltrim($values, ',');

        //statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . "(" . $columns . ") VALUES(" . $valueset . ")";

        //convert values to array
        $values = explode(',', $values);

        //query
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql)->execute($values);
        //$query = $conn->prepare($sql)->execute([$values]);;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `include`, not `include_once`. If you use `include_once`, then it won't execute the code in the file the second time you call the method.

But it would probably be better to include the file in the class's constructor, so you only need to execute it once, rather than create a new connection every time you perform a query. Make `$conn` a class property instead of an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 0):

The class below give the ability to get a connection object from **getInstance()** funtion, so you just include the Config class where you wanna communicate with database (**model**)

**getInstance()** : is singleton,  which means that you have a single instance

```
class Config{

    private $HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private $USERNAME = "root";
    private $PASSWORD = "";
    private $DATABASE = "edubits";
    private static $pdo = null;

    public static function getInstance($data = null){
        if(self::$pdo == null){
            self::PDOConnect($data = null);
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    } 

    private static function PDOConnect(){
        try{
            $info = new DBInfo($data);
            self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->HOSTNAME . ";dbname=" . $this->DATABASE . ";", $this->USERNAME, $this->PASSWORD);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo new PDOCustomException($e->getMessage(), null, $e);
        }
    }

    public function close(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here i've choice to use config directly from your **INSERT** function to get connection object, or get connexion object in constructor one time and use it many time in QUERY class

So connection instance is stored on **$cn**

```
include_once('../configuration.php');

class QUERY
{
    private $cn = null;
    private $DBAction = null;

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $cn = new DBAction();
            $this->cn = $cn::getInstance();
        } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
            throw new PDOCustomException($ex->getMessage(), null, $ex);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw new CustomException($ex->getMessage(), null, $ex);
        }
    }

    public function INSERT($table, $data, $conn) {
        $config = new Config();

        // variable declaration
        $columns = "";
        $valueset = "";
        $values = "";

        //loop
        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns = $columns . ', ' . $column;
            $valueset = $valueset . ', ?';
            $values = $values . ', ' . $value;
        }

        //trimming the first comma from the result above
        $columns = ltrim($columns, ',');
        $valueset = ltrim($valueset, ',');
        $values = ltrim($values, ',');

        //statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . "(" . $columns . ") VALUES(" . $valueset . ")";

        //convert values to array
        $values = explode(',', $values);

        //query
        $query = $this->cn->prepare($sql)->execute($values);

   }
}
```

Comment: This seems logical and a bit complicated to my understanding. More explanation is highly appreciated.